# When to Transplant Rose Cuttings

Tags: transplanting, propagation, roses

A few weeks back I took some cuttings from a rose bush and potted them following this guide: https://www.abc.net.au/gardening/factsheets/rose-rustling/9430144.

Since then I've learned the difference between hard and semi-hard cuttings and seen that I have a mix of both in three pots. The semi-hard ones have started to sprout leaves and the hard ones are just sitting there.

Can anyone tell me what will give me the best chance of keeping (at least a few of) these things alive, as I understand the hard ones should take months to root but the semi hard are possibly ready?

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If they are mixed in the pots,

- unpot them (all) with due care and gently
- plant on the ones that are ready now
- and repot the ones that are not ready now for further time.